# Creating 3D image slider for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, image, slideshow, slide

I have a more general coding question.

The App shazam are using a very cool design where you could slide images. I wonder what type of technique they most likely used to create this? I am interested in developing something similar for both Android and iOS.

Could there possibly be a tutorial or example code for something like this on the web? As far from what I've seen there are no "native" support for a design like this in iOS/Android? All experience is very appreciated. / Regards

[image]

Comment: Maybe  [this](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) can help

Comment: Looks great. Know anything about android ?

Comment: check my answer it should be a good starting point. don't forget to accept the answer if it helps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a good staring point:

**iOS**

[iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

[image: iCarousel]

**Android**

[SimpleInfiniteCarousel](https://github.com/mrleolink/SimpleInfiniteCarousel)

[image]

[CarouselViewProject](https://github.com/clkasd/CarouselViewProject)

[image: CarouselViewProject]